# Does Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS not come with a c compiler by default?

Tags: 20.04, gcc

I recently downloaded the official desktop version of 20.04.1 and installed it on a machine. I was surprised to find that there was no gcc command available! I installed it with apt but I always thought that every flavour of Linux came with gcc straight out of the box.

Has something recently changed in the release philosophy of Ubuntu?

Comment: No it doesn't, and whilst I can't confirm if it was ever a default,  I've always had to install `build-essential` manually (but I wasn't a user for 4.10).   *I would expect that, given most users of Ubuntu (inc. flavors) are users, and not developers*

Comment: I've never, ever had to do it before, going back to sometime before version 12. Also with Xbuntu, debian, all the raspbian flavours had it.

Comment: I mainly use *flavors*, and a QA install made today (*groovy* as that's the current testing release) doesn't have it installed, though some gcc-10 libraries are present (no `gcc` package for Lubuntu)  *Neither for Kubuntu 20.04.1*

Comment: Concur, `aptitude why gcc` on our 18.04 systems (Ubuntu, Lubuntu) gives `build-essential` as the reason for presence.

Answer (score 3):

The default version of gcc in Ubuntu 20.04 is gcc-9. Ubuntu 20.04 comes with gcc-9 installed by default which can be tested if it is installed by running `apt policy gcc-9`. gcc is the GNU C compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C. For more information type `man gcc`

gcc-10 is available in the default repositories of Ubuntu 20.04 and later. gcc-11 is available in Ubuntu 21.04 and later.

Comment: Well 20.04.1 - didn't have it, so there seems to some disagreement between those answering and commenting

Comment: @NickT I guess for a definitive answer one would need to scrape the `.manifest` files at [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) and/or [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

Comment: The .manifest file for 20.04 has gcc-9 and gcc-10 with gcc-9 being the default gcc.

Comment: Can we expect GCC11 to become available in ubuntu 20.04 repositories at some point?

Comment: @Silicomancer We don't expect gcc-11 to become available in 20.04, but I posted an answer about how to download gcc-11 manually from the default Ubuntu 21.04 repositories and install it in Ubuntu 20.04 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68426284/).

Comment: @Silicomancer The "28 things only developers will find funny" hyperlink on your profile tab at Ask Ubuntu and Stack Overflow is broken, but it can be replaced by [this archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130727082620/https://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/28-things-only-developers-will-find-funny).

Comment: @karel Ok, I will try your guide as soon as possible. Also changed the link, thanks! Do you know why GCC11 isn't on the roadmap? Ubuntu 20.04 is an LTs that will be supported quite some time... I would have expected to get GCC11 sooner or later.

Comment: @Silicomancer Please refer to this question : [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/)