# GCC compiling problem

Tags: bash, gcc, 21.04, c

I just downloaded the GCC compile for C/C++. After compiling with the command `gcc main.c -c -lGL -lGLU -lglut` I get a permission error which can be fixed by changing the permissions. I then get this error: `bash: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. Will you help me fix this? Also if it helps I'm using C.

-Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like it might be the wrong architecture: https://askubuntu.com/q/648555 .  What does `file ./main.o` return? or if `main.o` is not in the current directory, find the file and then run the `file` command on the `main.o` to show what type of file it is.

Comment: It might be possible that it was compiled for the wrong architecture but there could be other reasons. Also, did you install GCC by running `sudo apt install build-essential` ? This is the recommended way to download and install GCC.

Comment: After compiling **how**, exactly? The fact that your command produced a `.o` file suggests you added the `-c` option, which suppresses linking to a final executable file

Comment: @mchid Idk I forget how I installed the gcc compiler, but I did install the `build-essential` package after if that makes a difference

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the question with the exact command I used

Comment: @Dequog right - so remove the `-c` (and optionally add `-o progname` if you want the executable to be named `progname` rather than the default `a.out`).

Comment: @steeldriver now I'm getting this error: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function _start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Does `main.cpp` actually contain a `main` function? Is it **really** C or is it C++ (as suggested by the `.cpp` suffix)? If the latter, use `g++` in place of `gcc`. If the former (C with a `.cpp` suffix) you may need to add `-xc` to direct gcc appropriately.

Comment: sorry I meant to put `main.c` and yes it does contain the `main()` function also the `-xc` command does nothing

Comment: Did you download the C compiler from a non-Ubuntu source? Why not use the C compiler from the packaging system?

Comment: @waltinator I did use the c compiler from the packaging system

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965472)

Comment: @mchid no because 1. I defined a main function 2. my original command has the `-c` part which causes the other problem

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler needed downloading. My understanding is that gcc is built-in to all Ubuntu desktop versions.

Comment: @NickT Hey sorry it took me so long to answer, but not the gcc compiler wasn't automatically installed for me. Does it have something to do with me using the LTS version

Comment: It seems that I asked the very same question last year. Opinions vary as to whether it was built-in. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276468/does-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-not-come-with-a-c-compiler-by-default

Comment: I just for got to save the file sorry

Comment: When I compiled a program in Ubuntu, then moved the project (it was meson-based) into my Raspberry Pi, this warning printed. The fix was to rebuild.