# Why is GCC missing from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, compiling, gcc

I know that gcc is listed in the manifest files for 20.04, however, it seems that nearly all installations are missing it by default.

For some extra context, I work on a small OSS web project and since 20.04 started being the preferred version for our users we have been running into issues with it being missing from installs. This affects users installing from vps vendors as well as those installing from images directly from canonical. I even downloaded the ISO from the official site and installed in a VM, and sure enough it, GCC is not actually installed.

Why is this?

It seems a similar question was posted about a year ago ([Does Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS not come with a c compiler by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276468/does-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-not-come-with-a-c-compiler-by-default)) with no real answers.

Side Note: It appears that this might end up being the case for 22.04 as well.

**Edit:**
For clarity:

- I am talking about Ubuntu Server
- I personally have specifically tested 20.04.2, .3, and .4 on the amd64 architecture (though I do know people using the arm images with the same behavior, leading me to believe that architecture is entirely irrelevant to the issue)
- I am well aware that people on StackExchange do not work for Canonical, that is pretty obvious. That doesn't however mean that no one who might see thins could shed light on the reason for this.

Comment: That is not a question any of the volunteers here could answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available on many different ISOs, but you've provided no clues as to which you're talking about. You mention downloading one from the official site but which?  (it's available in server, desktop form, as well as *flavors*, 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, 20.04.3, 20.04.4, plus various different architectures, but you've not provided any specific ISO implying there is only a single one & there isn't)

Comment: @guiverc I am talking about Ubuntu Server. The architecture and specific version doesn't seem to make a difference, the most recent test I have done was 20.04.4 on the x86 architecture, however in the past I have tested 20.04.3 and .2 (admittedly not sure if I ever tested .1 or the original non-point release) on x86 and have had the same experience. I don't make use of arm so I cant speak to if that image works properly.

Comment: Just install it, gcc is in the repositories ... install gcc: `sudo apt install gcc` or `sudo apt install build-essential`  for a collection of tools for building software, incl. gcc.

Comment: I understand it can just be installed. I am trying to find an answer as to why the installed packages do not match the manifest provided by canonical.

Comment: The manifest contains what is included on the ISO, but what actually is installed depends on the options the installer selects, let alone some packages are never installed (who needs the `subiquity` (*or whatever installer is included on the chosen ISO*) on an installed system!).  Details such as Ubuntu Server belong in your question (*comments are from us to you*!), plus 20.04 isn't available for x86 (*i386* in Debian/Ubuntu terms) being only *amd64* or *x86_64* (ie. 64-bit); 32-bit only for *armhf* & architecture matters; how are we to know you don't mean *ppc64el*, or *s390x* if not told.

Comment: Please provide a link to the manifest you are looking at.

Comment: Simple answer: because Canonical has chosen so. We users of this site do not work for Canonical, so we cannot answer the question "why".